# firewalld not listing any active zones?

Tags: firewalld, firewalld-zone

When running

```
[root@host ~]# firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
[root@host ~]#
[root@host ~]# firewall-cmd --get-default-zone
public
```

I  am not getting any active zones. How can I activate a zone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You activate a zone by binding a network interface or source IP address range(s) to it. Any firewall rules in the zone then apply to that network interface or IP address range(s).

Comment: I also had to restart the service.

Comment: You can do this via `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --change-interface=eth0` (for example).

Comment: I think `--get-active-zones` should print the default zone as well. Maybe as `public (implicit) internal home` or whatever.

Comment: You need a `firewall-cmd --reload` after change interface command @negacao said to commit changes.

Answer (score 2):

On a similar case, I took a peek with `strace` and realized, that FirewallD had somehow lost D-Bus access completely.

The easiest fix was to reboot the Linux. That helped and FirewallD saw active zones again.

Comment: yep, that was the case for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, except I had definitely had an interface in a zone.
For me I had to restart the firewalld service.